# Parsing Whois Text Data using RubyWhois

Tags: ruby, whois-ruby

How do I parse pre-acquired whois text data using RubyWhois.

That is to say assuming that I already have the whois info of 'stackoverflow.com' as a string. How do I parse the same using RubyWhois library?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I found the solution here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ruby-whois/1ZpG_yfCqTM/discussion

Comment: can't access the page , how to gain the access ?